# Camera isn't working when trying to save in internal folder using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I am trying to take a image and save in internal storage inside a folder for app specific images. But for some reason its not working- camera is opening but after taking picture its not returning back to activity. Below is the code:

**In Manifest:**

```
<application   .. >
   <activity .... >

   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/shared_file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**In res/xml/shared_file_paths.xml:**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="CameraPicture" path="data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images/" />
</paths>
```

**In MainActivity.java:**

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            takePictureImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.take_picture_image_view);
            ........

            takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                       File outputImageFile = func_createFolder();

                        if(outputImageFile!=null) {
                            outputImgUri = getImageFileUriByOsVersion(outputImageFile);
                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputImgUri);

                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(TakePictureActivity.this, "Problem creating file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                }    });
        }


         private File func_createFolder()
        {
            File outputImageFile = null;

            //File mydir  = getExternalCacheDir();
            File mydir = new File("data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images");

            if (!mydir.exists())
                {  if (!mydir.mkdirs()) { Log.d("TAG_LOG_TAKE_PICTURE", "failed to create directory");
                                            return null;}      }

            String imageFileName = "colorAppImg_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
            outputImageFile = new File(mydir, imageFileName);

            try {outputImageFile.createNewFile();}
            catch(Exception exp){Log.d("TAG_LOG_TAKE_PICTURE", ""+exp);}

             return outputImageFile;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            try { if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                        InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(outputImgUri);
                        Bitmap pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        takePictureImageView.setImageBitmap(pictureBitmap);
                    }   }
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
                {    Log.e(TAG_LOG_TAKE_PICTURE, ex.getMessage(), ex);    }
        }


         private Uri getImageFileUriByOsVersion(File file)
        {
            Uri ret = null;

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                {  Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
                    ret = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, getPackageName() + ".provider", file); }
            else
                ret = Uri.fromFile(file);

            return ret;
        }
```

but if I make the file in cache directory by changing the below code inside func_createFolder() then it works and show the image in imageview

```
File mydir = new File("data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images");
```

to

```
File mydir  = getExternalCacheDir();
```

But if i don't create it in cache , instead create in internal storage then the file gets created with filesize 0 and the app gets stuck in camera-doesn't get back to activity to show image in imageview.

Comment: `<external-path name="CameraPicture" path="data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images/" />
</paths>` change to `<internal-path name="CameraPicture" path="." />
</paths>`.

Comment: `new File("data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images");` That should be `new File("/data/data/com.simlelifesolution.mycameraapp/ColorApp_Images");`.